# ORA-22905 - when querying a table type with a select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
 DECLARE
 TYPE record_AB IS RECORD
   (
      AA              VARCHAR2 (16 BYTE),
      BB    VARCHAR2 (16 BYTE)
   );

  TYPE type_tab_AB IS TABLE OF record_AB
                        INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

  tab_AB   type_tab_AB;

  BEGIN
   SELECT *
    BULK COLLECT INTO tab_AB FROM...
    ..
    SELECT * FROM TABLE (tab_AB) ;
```

I get "ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item" when it gets to the SELECT from TABLE statement.

Is it even possibile to query a table type within PLSQL?

Comment: I think this needs more context. Can you post a _complete_ minimal example that demonstrates this error? You must be populating `tab_AB` with multiple records in your procedure for this to work in which case why are you selecting into this variable at all.

Comment: I think that this functionality may have been added in 12C.  I got this error by trying to run a script that worked everywhere else on Oracle 11.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It is possible to query table types in PL/SQL, but only nested tables and varrays whose types are declared at schema-level, i.e. outside of PL/SQL.

The error

> ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item

means that you are trying to query from an unsupported table type.  Your type `type_tab_AB` is an associative array, because of the `INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER` clause.  Remove the `INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER` clause to make your `type_tab_AB` a nested table type.  (Varrays would also work here, but I wouldn't recommend using them unless you know an upper bound for the number of rows to expect.  When declaring a varray type, you need to specify the maximum number of elements, whereas nested table types have no such restriction.)

After making this change, your code may still not work.  The next error you may get (see note at bottom if you don't) is

> PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements

This is because the type you are selecting into is declared inside PL/SQL.  You need to declare `type_tab_AB`, and `record_AB` outside of PL/SQL, using `CREATE TYPE ...`.

The next problem you encounter will be because of the keyword `RECORD`.  Record types can only be created inside PL/SQL, [they cannot be created at schema level](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#i20479).  Change `RECORD` to `OBJECT` to fix this.

The last problem you will encounter is with the `SELECT t.AA, t.BB BULK COLLECT INTO tab_AB FROM ...` statement.  As it stands, this query will give you the following error:

> PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values

You are selecting two items from each row and are providing only one table to bulk-insert the data into.  Oracle can't quite figure out that you want to stuff the two items into your `record_AB` type.  You can fix this fairly easily by changing the query to `SELECT record_AB(t.AA, t.BB) BULK COLLECT INTO tab_AB FROM ...`.

Collectively these changes should fix the problem.  Here's a full SQL*Plus script that creates a test table with some test data and verifies that it can query the table type:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (AA VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), BB VARCHAR2(16 BYTE));

INSERT INTO some_table (AA, BB) VALUES ('aa 1', 'bb 1');
INSERT INTO some_table (AA, BB) VALUES ('aaaaaaaaaa 2', 'b 2');
INSERT INTO some_table (AA, BB) VALUES ('aaaaa 3', 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbb 3');
COMMIT;

VARIABLE curs REFCURSOR;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE record_AB AS OBJECT
   (
      AA    VARCHAR2 (16 BYTE),
      BB    VARCHAR2 (16 BYTE)
   );
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE type_tab_AB IS TABLE OF record_AB;
/

DECLARE
  tab_AB   type_tab_AB;
BEGIN
  SELECT record_AB(t.AA, t.BB)
    BULK COLLECT INTO tab_AB 
    FROM some_table t;

  OPEN :curs FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE (tab_AB) ;
END;
/

PRINT :curs
```

I've put the result of `SELECT`ing the contents of `tab_AB` into a cursor, and used a SQL*Plus cursor variable to list its contents.  The output I get when I run the script on Oracle 11g XE, after all of the 'Type created' and 'PL/SQL procedure successfully completed' messages, is as follows:

```
AA               BB
---------------- ----------------
aa 1             bb 1
aaaaaaaaaa 2     b 2
aaaaa 3          bbbbbbbbbbbbbb 3
```

*NOTE:* For simplicity, I've assumed the questioner is using Oracle 11 or older.  In Oracle 12, I believe you are allowed to use types declared in PL/SQL in a SQL query, so you may not encounter the PLS-00642 error.  I can't say what other changes to my answer might also be necessary for Oracle 12 as I have yet to use Oracle 12.

Comment: `but only nested tables` Not nested tables only. You can use `table` operator with variable arrays SQL data types also.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov: thanks, I didn't know that.  I've updated my answer to mention varrays.  I can't say I've used varrays before, and I don't think they would work particularly well here.  It's a shame that that Oracle error message implies only nested tables work with the `TABLE` operator.

Comment: I'm using both oracle 12 and 11 and just encountered this error porting app from 12 to 11 trying to select from table type declared at specification level. Thanks!

Comment: Changing `record` to `object` isn't the only way. Pipelined functions returning tables of records can be queried by SQL

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the example. Worked like a charm. This is exactly what i needed

Comment: In Oracle 19c:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/static-sql.html#GUID-65ADB424-2C2D-49ED-9E98-99A3A68BA248
You can query a collection if all of the following are true:
* The data type of the collection was either created at schema level or declared in a package specification.
* The data type of the collection element is either a scalar data type, a user-defined type, or a record type.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot query a type created inside a pl/sql block. You need to create it at sql prompt and then you can query it. See exmaple below :

```
scott@ORA92> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE emp_type AS OBJECT
  2    (id   NUMBER,
  3     name VARCHAR2(20));
  4  /

Type created.

scott@ORA92> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE emp_tab AS TABLE OF emp_type;
  2  /

Type created.

scott@ORA92> VARIABLE g_ref REFCURSOR
scott@ORA92> DECLARE
  2    employees emp_tab := emp_tab();
  3  BEGIN
  4    employees.EXTEND(2);
  5    employees(1) := emp_type (1, 'name1');
  6    employees(2) := emp_type (2, 'name2');
  7    OPEN :g_ref FOR
  8    SELECT * FROM TABLE (CAST (employees AS emp_tab));
  9  END;
 10  /
```