# Oracle: Pure PL/SQL data extraction and anonymization using temporary tables, read-only permissions

Tags: oracle, plsql, temp-tables, anonymize

I am trying to create a PL/SQL script that extracts a root "object" together with all children and other relevant information from an oracle production database. The purpose is to create a set of test-data to recreate issues that are encountered in production. Due to data protection laws the data needs to be anonymized when extracted - object names, certain types of id's, and monetary amounts need to be replaced.

I was trying to create one or more temporary translation tables, which would contain both the original values and anonymized versions. Then I would join the real data with the translation tables and output the anonymized values wherever required.

```
DECLARE
  rootId integer := 123456;

  TYPE anonTableRow IS RECORD 
  (
    id NUMBER,
    fieldC NUMBER,
    anonymizedFieldC NUMBER
  );

  TYPE anonTable IS TABLE OF anonTableRow;
  anonObject anonTable;
BEGIN

  FOR cursor_row IN 
  (
    select 
     id,
     fieldC,
     1234 -- Here I would create anonymized values based on rowNum or something similar
    from 
    prodTable
    where id = rootId
  ) 
  LOOP       
    i := i + 1;
    anonObject(i) := cursor_row; 
  END LOOP;

  FOR cursor_row IN 
  (
    select 
    prod_table.id,
    prod_table.fieldB,
    temp_table.anonymizedFieldC fieldC,
    prod_table.fieldD
    from 
    prod_table
    inner join table(temp_table) on prod_table.id = temp_table.id
    where prod_table.id = 123456789
  ) 
  LOOP       
   dbms_output.put_line('INSERT INTO prod_table VALUES (' || cursor_row.id || ', ' || cursor_row.fieldB || ', ' || cursor_row.fieldC || ', , ' || cursor_row.fieldD);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

However I ran into several problems with this approach - it seems to be near impossible to join oracle PL/SQL tables with real database tables. My access to the production database is severely restricted, so I cannot create global temporary tables, declare types outside PL/SQL or anything of that sort.

My attempt to declare my own PL/SQL types failed with the problems [mentioned in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208264/ora-22905-when-quering-a-table-type-with-a-select-statement) - the solution does not work for me because of the limited permissions.

Is there a pure PL/SQL way that does not require fancy permissions to achieve something like the above?

**Please Note:** The above code example is simplified a lot and would not really require a separate translation table - in reality I need access to the original and translated values in several different queries, so I would prefer not having to "recalculate" translations everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is properly normalized, then I guess this should only be necessary for internal IDs (not sure why you need to translate them though).

The following code should work for you, keeping the mappings in [Associative Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm):

```
DECLARE
  TYPE t_number_mapping IS TABLE OF PLS_INTEGER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

  mapping_field_c   t_number_mapping;
BEGIN
  -- Prepare mapping
  FOR cur IN (
    SELECT 101 AS field_c FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 102 FROM dual -- test-data
  ) LOOP
    mapping_field_c(cur.field_c) := mapping_field_c.COUNT;  -- first entry mapped to 1
  END LOOP;

  -- Use mapping
  FOR cur IN (
    SELECT 101 AS field_c FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 102 FROM dual -- test-data
  ) LOOP
    -- You can use the mapping when generating the `INSERT` statement
    dbms_output.put_line( cur.field_c || ' mapped to ' || mapping_field_c(cur.field_c) );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Output:

```
101 mapped to 1
102 mapped to 2
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach looks like it might be usable for me, I'll have to do some testing for the more advanced mappings though.

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't a permanent piece of production code, how about "borrowing" an existing collection type - e.g. one define in SYS that you can access.

Using this script from your schema you can generate a SQL Plus script to describe all SYS-owned types:

```
select 'desc ' || type_name from all_types
where typecode = 'COLLECTION'
and owner = 'SYS';
```

Running the resulting script will show you the structure of all the ones you can access.  This one looks potentially suitable for example:

```
SQL> desc KU$_PARAMVALUES1010
 KU$_PARAMVALUES1010 TABLE OF SYS.KU$_PARAMVALUE1010
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 PARAM_NAME                                         VARCHAR2(30)
 PARAM_OP                                           VARCHAR2(30)
 PARAM_TYPE                                         VARCHAR2(30)
 PARAM_LENGTH                                       NUMBER
 PARAM_VALUE_N                                      NUMBER
 PARAM_VALUE_T                                      VARCHAR2(4000)
```

Of course, you can't guarantee that type will still exist or be the same or be accessible to you after a database upgrade, hence my caveat at the start.

Answer (score 0):

More generic way to achieve this goal. 
In my example i'm using xquery flwor expressions and [dbms_xmlstore](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16659/xdb_dbmstore.htm). Knowledge about xquery is mandatory.

`create table  mask_user_objects as select * from user_objects where rownum <0;`

```
declare 
   v_s_table varchar2(30) := 'USER_OBJECTS';   --uppercase!!!
   v_d_table varchar2(30) := 'MASK_USER_OBJECTS';  --uppercase!!!
   v_mask_columns xmltype := xmltype('<COLS><OBJECT_NAME>XXXX</OBJECT_NAME>
                                            <DATA_OBJECT_ID>-1</DATA_OBJECT_ID>
                                            <OBJECT_TYPE/>                                            
                                      </COLS>');  --uppercase!!!   
   insCtx DBMS_XMLSTORE.ctxType;
   r NUMBER;
   v_source_table xmltype;
   v_cursor sys_refcursor; 
begin 
   open v_cursor  for 'select * from '||v_s_table||' where rownum <100 ';  
   v_source_table := xmltype(v_cursor);
   close v_cursor; 
   -- Load source table into xmltype. 
   insCtx := DBMS_XMLSTORE.newContext(v_d_table); -- Get saved context
  for rec in ( 
   select tt.column_value from  xmltable('
                  let $col := $anomyze/COLS
                  for $i in  $doc/ROWSET/ROW           
                   let $row := $i  
                   return <ROWSET>             
                            <ROW>                                         
                                {                                                                
                                 for $x in $row/* 
                                  return if(
                                       exists($col/*[name() = $x/name()] )                                                                                             
                                  ) then element{$x/name()}{ $col/*[name() = $x/name()]/text() }  
                                    else element{$x/name()}{$x/text()}                   
                                }                   
                            </ROW>             
                         </ROWSET>
                  '
                  passing v_source_table as "doc"
                       ,  v_mask_columns as "anomyze"
                  ) tt) loop
                  null;
             r := DBMS_XMLSTORE.insertXML(insCtx,  rec.column_value);
end loop;
 DBMS_XMLSTORE.closeContext(insCtx);      

end;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to try and help. I'm afraid that your solution looks more complex than what I am willing to try out right now, so I cannot verify whether it merits an upvote for the time being. I hope I'll be able to check it out in the future though.