# Call Function in package that return Table preventing SQL injection

Tags: java, spring, oracle, sql-injection

I have a Oracle Function inside Package which i can't change. My function returns a table of record.
To get the records i want, i am using the following Query where FUN_WF_BLOCO1_CC_MOVIMENTOS is my function

`SELECT * FROM TABLE  (Schema.Function('474','0000',1119940000084,'1997-02-23','2017-03-07','M',0,999999999999999.99))`

What's the best way to call it on a SpringBoot application?
I have tried many alternatives and the only way i could find is

```
    List<ConsultaMovimentoOutput> lst = null;
    String sqlQuery = "SELECT *  FROM TABLE  (Schema.Function(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?))";
    sqlQuery = Utils.resolveSqlArgs(sqlQuery, filter.getZcliente(), filter.getCkbalcao(), filter.getCknumcta(),
            filter.getDtinicio(), filter.getDtfim(), filter.getTpdata(), filter.getVlmovmin(),
            filter.getVlmovmax());

    try {
        lst = jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, new ConsultaMovimentoRowMapper());
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failure in Consulta Movimentos ", e);
    }

    return lst;


public static String resolveSqlArgs(String sql, Object... args) {

    String temp = sql.replace("?", "'%s'");
    temp = String.format(temp, args);

    return temp;
}
```

I am using sql.replace to replace my args for the '?' but i think this is very weak to prevent SQL injection.
Is there a better way to make my query than a `SELECT * FROM TABLE`?
I can't use preparedStatement because i have values to set but no variables to set in my query like a "where" or "like" clause.
Is there a better way to do this without sql.replace?

Thank you

[EDIT]

I have the following code that returns ORA-22905 using MapSqlParameterSource

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("SELECT *  FROM TABLE  (Schema.Function(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ))");

Object[] params = new Object[]{
    consultaMovimentosFilter.getzClienteIn(), 
    consultaMovimentosFilter.getCkBalcao(),
    Long.parseLong(consultaMovimentosFilter.getNrProces()),
    consultaMovimentosFilter.getDtFim(),
    consultaMovimentosFilter.getDtFim(),
    consultaMovimentosFilter.getIdDtValMov(),
    Long.parseLong(consultaMovimentosFilter.getVlMontMin()),
    Double.parseDouble(consultaMovimentosFilter.getVlMonMax())
};

List<ConsultaMovimentosOut> lst = null;
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();

return jdbcTemplate.query(query.toString(), params, new ConsultaMovimentosRowMapper());
```

my jdbctemplate is Autowired:

```
  @Autowired
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

[EDIT 2]

Server error:

> 2018-04-04 11:59:09.895 DEBUG 1096 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory    : SQL error codes for 'Oracle' found
>   2018-04-04 11:59:09.895 DEBUG 1096 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory    : Caching SQL error codes for DataSource [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@4ffced4e]: database product name is 'Oracle'
>   2018-04-04 11:59:09.895 DEBUG 1096 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.j.s.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator : Unable to translate SQLException with Error code '22905', will now try the fallback translator
>   2018-04-04 11:59:09.895 DEBUG 1096 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.j.s.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator   : Extracted SQL state class '99' from value '99999'
>   2018-04-04 11:59:09.905 ERROR 1096 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.t.n.w.services.web.Bloco1Controller    : Exception ocurred in findAllDetalheContrato
>
> org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT *  FROM TABLE  (schema.Function(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ))]; SQL state [99999]; error code [22905]; ORA-22905: não é possível ter acesso a linhas a partir de um item de uma tabela não encadeada
>   ; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-22905: não é possível ter acesso a linhas a partir de um item de uma tabela não encadeada
>
> at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]

Comment: Are you looking for [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)?

Comment: I cant use preparedStatement at least in a standar way because the return of my function is a table and i dont have where clauses. If i use preparedStatement i get an ORA-22905

Comment: Now *that* is a problem worth looking at. Post the code with the `PreparedStatement` and the full exception. I don't think you need `WHERE` or `LIKE` clauses to be able to use `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: I have edited and posted the code. Cant write it on here because its to long

Comment: And the exception you are getting, including details?

Comment: the log doens't add much but i posted it anyway. I dont know why but somehow the arguments are not been parsed to the query

Comment: The arguments are getting passed fine, they normally show up as `?` in a stack trace. Your problem is the ORA-22905 - a `TABLE of RECORD` can only be used in PL/SQL, not SQL. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208264/ora-22905-when-querying-a-table-type-with-a-select-statement

Comment: @kfinity tks. The problem is that i cant change the PL/SQL. I think the only solution is to use a sql.replace, to replace ? for arguments which is a problem because of the injection