# defining collection type in package

Tags: oracle, plsql

When creating a collection type on schema level, this test package compiles fine:

```
create type table_of_ids as table of number;

create or replace package test_package as
    procedure test_p(my_input table_of_ids);
end;

create or replace
    package body test_package as

    procedure test_p(my_input table_of_ids) as
        res_tab table_of_ids;
    begin
        select res_id bulk collect
          into res_tab
          from test_table
         where id in (select column_value from table (my_input));
        null;
    end test_p;

end test_package;
```

But when I try to define the collection type within the package, it failed:

```
create or replace package test_package as
    type my_table is table of number;
    procedure test_p(my_input my_table);
end;

create or replace
    package body test_package as

    procedure test_p(my_input my_table) as
        res_tab my_table;
    begin
        select res_id bulk collect
          into res_tab
          from test_table
         where id in (select column_value from table (my_input));
        null;
    end test_p;

end test_package;
```

The message I receive is:

```
Error(8,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(8,107): PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
Error(8,113): PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statement
```

So, does this mean I cannot define this type only within the package? Or what am I missing?

Comment: yes you can't select  from a collection defined in a package. it should be on Schema level

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-22905 - when querying a table type with a select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208264/ora-22905-when-querying-a-table-type-with-a-select-statement)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this thread. According to the example given in the [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS00511) I can define collection types within the package and can use it to iterate over them, but not inside a sql statement? Where does this restriction come from?

Comment: i found this [link](http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2016/02/use-table-operator-with-associative.html) and this one in a [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/static.htm#LNPLS491) it Looks like you can use a table Operator starting with Oracle 12.1. what Version do you use?

Comment: The restriction is that the SQL engine (even in a PL/SQL context) doesn't understand/allow PL/SQL data structures. Except that sometimes it does, and things improve a bit in later versions.

Comment: @hotfix: I'm still on 11g. One more reason to motivate our dba's to upgrade ;)